# Purchase event GA Web & App not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, firebase-analytics

Note that I am fairly new to this kind of work, and I am trying to figure out how JavaScript/dataLayer etc works.

I am currently looking into the implementation of the new GA Web & App Property that Google is providing us. One of the implementations I want to make, is the implementation where we measure an Purchase event with corresponding Key value pairs (parameters) which we want to send through the dataLayer to Analytics/BigQuery.

Google offers us official documentation on 'how to' implement this through the dataLayer using a dataLayer.push method. For 99% of all events, this works. However, when it comes to the Purchase event, it doesn't work. Or atleast, to me it seems it is not working, as I do not get the desired information into BigQuery that I am sending over with the dataLayer.push event.

I get the following issue when I am trying to follow Google's approach:

Google's approach (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-appweb#measure_purchases):

```js
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'purchase':, {
    "transaction_id": "T12345",
    "value": 35.78,
    "currency": "USD",
    "tax": 2.03,
    "shipping": 0,
    "coupon": "free_shipping",
  'ecommerce': {
    'items': [{
      'item_name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt', // Name or ID is required.
      'item_id': '67890',
      'price': '33.75',
      'item_brand': 'Google',
      'item_category': 'Apparel',
      'item_category_2': 'Mens',
      'item_category_3': 'Shirts',
      'item_category_4': 'Tshirts',
      'item_variant': 'Black',
      'item_list_name': 'Search Results',
      'item_list_id': 'SR123',
      'index': 2,
      'quantity': '1'
    }]
  }
});
```

My different implementation versions in order to try and fix it somehow:

Single quotes instead of double:

```js
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'purchase':, {
    'transaction_id': 'T12345',
    'value': 35.78,
    'currency': 'USD',
    'tax': 2.03,
    'shipping': 0,
    'coupon': 'free_shipping',
  'ecommerce': {
    'items': [{
      'item_name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt', // Name or ID is required.
      'item_id': '67890',
      'price': '33.75',
      'item_brand': 'Google',
      'item_category': 'Apparel',
      'item_category_2': 'Mens',
      'item_category_3': 'Shirts',
      'item_category_4': 'Tshirts',
      'item_variant': 'Black',
      'item_list_name': 'Search Results',
      'item_list_id': 'SR123',
      'index': 2,
      'quantity': '1'
    }]
  }
});
```

Putting ecommerce in front of the 'transaction_id' for example;

```js
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'purchase',
 'ecommerce': {
    'transaction_id': 'T12345',
    'value': 13.00,
    'currency': 'USD',
    'tax': 2.03,
    'shipping': 0,
    'coupon': 'free_shipping',
  'items': [{
    'item_name': '09:00',
    'item_id': '737|24-07-2020|09.00|test',
    'price': 13.00,
    'item_category': '9 test/test/737-the-test',
    'item_category2': 'true/false',
    'item_variant': 'exclusive/non-exclusive',
    'index': '1',
    'quantity': 1
    }]
   }
  })
```

Putting ecommerce information in the items array:

```js
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'purchase',
 'ecommerce': {
  'items': [{
    'transaction_id': 'T12345',
    'value': 13.00,
    'currency': 'USD',
    'tax': 2.03,
    'shipping': 0,
    'coupon': 'free_shipping',
      'item_name': '09:00',
      'item_id': '737|24-07-2020|09.00|test',
      'price': 13.00,
      'item_category': '9 test/test/737-the-test',
      'item_category2': 'true/false',
      'item_variant': 'exclusive/non-exclusive',
      'index': '1',
      'quantity': 1
    }]
   }
  })
```

In conclusion: I do get all of the information from items.>, but I do not get all of the information from  ecommerce whilst I am pushing it into the dataLayer. Also note that I have tested that it does correctly get pushed into the dataLayer, it just somehow disappears during the transition from dataLayer to BigQuery. This DOES make sense if the parameters do not exist (since I have to use the official event names and Parameters that Google provides). However, the ecommerce parameters I've listed do all officially exist.

So my question is: has someone encountered the same problems? Or is there someone that knows a way to bypass this problem?

Comment: A little late but someone told me that price property must be a string